# Conexões de Banco de Dados no Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo mobile usando Unity 3D e preciso ter uma base de dados local no dispositivo. Qual banco de dados usar? Tem como usar MySQL, SQLite. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Olá eu geralmente estou utilizando o Mysql, o comando que eu utilizava já faz um tempo que uso e eu acho bom, pois você pode utilizar uma linguagem de back end no caso eu usei o PHP.

O comando consiste em retornar uma string HTML e você transformar em um vetor onde você pode recuperar os dados. No caso você tem que separar os dados por uma string, no caso eu escolhi p * "asterisco".

Código em C#.

```
var form = new WWWForm();
        //aqui você adiciona como método post o campo ID
        form.AddField("id", id);
        WWW w = new WWW("http://localhost/teste.php", form);
        yield return w;   
        if (w.error != null) {
            print(w.error); //if there is an error, tell us
        } 
        else {
            formText = w.text; //here we return the data our PHP told us
            stringToEdit = formText;
            string[] temp = w.text.Split("*".ToCharArray());
            stringToEdit = w.text;

            nome_pers = temp[0];
            STR = int.Parse(temp[1]);
            AGI = int.Parse(temp[2]);
            DEX = int.Parse(temp[3]);
            INT = int.Parse(temp[4]);
            VIT = int.Parse(temp[5]);
            CAR = int.Parse(temp[6]);
}
```

No PHP ou na linguagem que você queria você faz a requisição no banco de dados e retorna várias strings mandando escrever no os dados no HTML, no caso eu passei o campo ID como post na parte do:

```
 form.AddField("id", id);
    WWW w = new WWW("http://localhost/teste.php", form);
    yield return w;
```

E o código php fiz assim:

```
<?php
include 'conectar.php';
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$id = substr($id, 0,-7); // retorna "d"


$sql = "SELECT `id_conta` , `id_personagem` , `id_raça` , `str` , `agi` , `dex` , `int` , `vit` , `car` , `nome` , partida.ordem, partida.id_partida
FROM `peronagem`
INNER JOIN partida ON ( id_personagem = partida.id_pe )
WHERE id_personagem = '$id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

    echo $row['nome'].'*';
    echo $row['str'].'*';
    echo $row['agi'].'*';
    echo $row['dex'].'*';
    echo $row['int'].'*';
    echo $row['vit'].'*';
    echo $row['car'].'*';
    echo $row['ordem'].'*';
    echo $row['id_conta'].'*';
    echo $row['id_raça'].'*';
}
```

?>

Fiz este código já faz um bom tempo então se tiver uma maneira melhor me avisem, caso queria ver o manual está aqui: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

A vantagem de utilizar no back end e não usar um comando C# é que as pessoas não podem roubar seus dados de conexão ao BD (Por engenharia reversa), os dados ficam mais seguros. Ai é só aplicar a segurança no back end contra hack, (sql injection, etc...), no front end colocar um obfuscator para dificultar quem quer clonar seu game através de engenharia reversa.

Se preferir você pode utilizar a linguagem de programação que quiser e com o framework que preferir para o back end.